# onLocationChanged in LocationListener can't write to thread

Tags: android, multithreading, locationmanager

I have an acivity and a separate serverthread. The server thread is connect to a server.
In the activity I have a LocationListener. The onLocationChanged is sending data to the serverthread, but my data will not reach the server.

If i'm sending data directly from my activity, it works fine.

can some one help me?

Comment: I doubt we can help you without seeing what you are doing... Post your relevant code.

Comment: If you're accessing user interface elements from an independent thread, you need to separate your UI interface changes to a RunOnUIThread

Answer (score 0):

An independent thread may not access UI elements. You should look at the [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Cant understand the exact problem without seeing code..but as per my understanding
you can try this -

Use handler in your serverthread to receive data from UI thread.

for example in your serverthread runnable -

```
@Override
public void run(){
       Looper.prepare();

       mHandler = new Handler() {
               public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                   // Act on the message
               }
       };
       Looper.loop();
}
```

from onLocationChanged() , you can post message to the handler.

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

 Message m = new Message();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(DATA_KEY, "location specific data");
 m.setData(bundle);
 mHandler.sendMessage(m);

 }
```